# What is the temperature of the black hole?

Tags: black-hole

Are black holes hot or cold? I was thinking because I wanted to know if there any human sustainable temperature so we can travel in it.

Comment: Forget about traveling there. There's no solid surface to stand on, not to mention that doing so would turn you into a puddle of neutrons anyways.

Comment: What kind of energy is present in there?

Comment: Related question: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/26427/24157

Answer (score 3):

See [Hawking radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawking_radiation). The temperature of a black hole depends on its mass, and is given by:

$T=\frac{hc^3}{16\pi^2GMk_B}$

Where $h$ is the Planck constant, $c$ is the speed of light, $G$ is Newton's gravitational constant, $M$ is the mass of the black hole, and $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant.

Comment: There's a nice [Hawking radiation calculator](https://www.vttoth.com/CMS/physics-notes/311-hawking-radiation-calculator)

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the temperature of the event horizon, then it depends on the mass. Super-massive black holes have a temperature of $1.4 \times 10^{-14}$ Kelvin while a solar mass black hole has a temperature of only $6.0 \times 10^{-8}$ Kelvin. This temperature comes from the proposed Hawking radiation of black holes$^1$. The reference below gives some temperatures for very small black holes.

1. https://phys.org/news/2016-09-cold-black-holes.html